# Dynamic loading of modules/components in decorators

Tags: angular

I'm building CRM system.
Some of my clients want to personalize their version so depending on subdomain I want to load different components and modules for routing modules.

Something like this:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: PageAuthContainerComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'login',
// get custom component if needen for subdomain
        component: SubdomainsLoader.loadComponent('PageAuthLogowanieComponent') || PageAuthLogowanieComponent,
      },
      {path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full'},
    ],
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
 // get additional modules for subdomain
    ...SubdomainsLoader.loadModules('AuthPagesRoutingModule'),
  ],
  declarations: [],
  exports: []
})
export class AuthPagesRoutingModule {
}
```

It works in developement, but problem is with `AOT`. I cannot use functions in decorators.
Is there a way to handle those kind of cases?
Or maybe only solution is to use `production` without `aot` and wait for `Ivy` and hope it will solve problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular provides lazy load of modules. So you can maintain two version modules `Version1Module` and `Version2Module` and so on. Based on the route you can load either of the module. Hence, you need not to think about dynamic loading of modules, rather angular will take care of it.

Refer: [Angular lazy modules](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules)

**Version1Module**

```ts
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    children: [
      {
        path: 'login',
        component: PageAuthContainerComponent,
      },
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
    ],
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
  ],
  declarations: [],
  exports: []
})
export class Version1Module { }
```

**Version2Module**

```ts
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    children: [
      {
        path: 'login',
        component: PageAuthContainerComponent1,  // Or can be same component as of version 1
      },
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
    ],
  },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes),
  ],
  declarations: [],
  exports: []
})
export class Version2Module { }
```

**AppModule (Main module)**

```ts
const versionToLoad = (window.location.hostname || "").includes('v1subdomain') ? './apps/v1/version1.module#Version1Module' : './apps/v2/version2.module#Version2Module';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'app',
    loadChildren: versionToLoad
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
  ],
  declarations: [],
  exports: []
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Ok - user goes to `app/v1` page and it loads `Version1Module` (it's first). How can I depend it on `subdomain`?

Comment: It's not a good solution for me. I would have to change my `routerlinks` and I even don't know which routes will be changed (don't know future clients' requirements).

Comment: I guess this might solve your problem with updated answer.

Comment: It's not working - angular can't see new modules, even without aot. I've made some tests and I think reason is that angular compiler can't find lazy loaded modules and therefore are not in bundles.

Comment: After adding `lazyModules` to `angular.json` (https://netbasal.com/the-need-for-speed-lazy-load-non-routable-modules-in-angular-30c8f1c33093) it's working, but You have to use full path (starting from `src/app`). Thanks, tough it's much more boilerplate.

Comment: You can edit anwser (adding info about `lazyModules` in `angular.json`) and I'll mark it as correct.